# Why would you use a HTML/CSS width of 99.9% instead of 100%?

Tags: html, css, haslayout

I have seen many developers writing HTML or CSS inline style widths of 99.9% in places where I would use 100%.  Is there any valid reason for using 99.9%?  Does it have any effective difference from 100%?

EDIT to retweet MSalters' very good question: `Considering that 99.9% is one pixel off above 500 pixels, why not 99.99%?`  I'd guess he's right, that if you're going with the `dirty hack` you should use 99.99%, does anyone disagree?

Additional References:

- @Michael Stum's comment about the CSS zoom property led me to this interesting link about triggering hasLayout with `zoom`: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1354-The-Power-Of-ZOOM-Fixing-CSS-Issues-In-Internet-Explorer.htm.
- @Andrew Dunn offered this incredibly comprehensive link on hasLayout: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## The `hasLayout` property

It's a dirty hack used to set the IE specific `hasLayout` property of the element to true. The `hasLayout` property "determines how elements draw and bound their content, interact with and relate to other elements, and react on and transmit application/user events." Giving an element `layout` is an easy way to fix many layout related bugs which appear in Internet Explorer.

### What's with the 99.9%?

Setting the width to 99.9% is one way to trigger it. The reason you would use 99.9% is because layout is given to an element if its `width` is set to anything other than `auto`. Setting it to a percentage prevents the need to use a fixed width.

After some testing in jsFiddle, I've come to the conclusion that it really isn't necessary to to use a width of 99.9%, using a width of 100% is just as effective. http://jsfiddle.net/3qfjW/2/ (IE-Only). It seems that setting `width` to 99.9% may have been a [common misconception](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/#comment-307) which stuck.. ***Spread the word people.***

### Other methods

You can also trigger `hasLayout` using `zoom: 1;` While this is the preferred method for many, as it doesn't mess with other style related features of an element, it is also invalid CSS code, which is not an option to use for some developers.

---

### Further Reading

For more methods to trigger `hasLayout` check out: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

For more information on the `hasLayout` property check out the MSDN article on `hasLayout` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481(VS.85).aspx (This is actually a great read, lots of detailed information)

Comment: Ah, you got it while I was still looking up references. +1.

Comment: Considering that 99.9% is one pixel off above 500 pixels, why not 99.99% ?

Comment: Seems weird to use width, when zoom: 1 also exists.

Comment: Yep, I personally use `zoom: 1` for my projects, although some people avoid using it because it is a proprietary Microsoft CSS rule which invalidates your CSS.

Answer (score 3):

It's true `width` of anything but `auto` and `zoom` trigger hasLayout, and `zoom` is the more flexible property/value since it doesn't mess with the width but I don't think that's the reason why you saw the developers use 99.9%.

In certain floating cases it's necessary that the combined width of the floats do not add up to 100% ( if specified in percentages ) because IE6 incorrectly calculates that as beyond 100% and usually the latter float drops.

The solution is to either specify a -1px right margin just for IE or make the sum 99.99%.

I have documented the bug [here](http://work.arounds.org/issue/61/floated-elements-combined-width-100-causes-float-d/). So whether it is related or not to what you were seeing, hope the bug link helps anyone experiencing it.

Comment: Wouldn't they still round up with a width of 99.99% though? I'm pretty sure the only safe way is to take off 1px from the margin.

Comment: It's very common for developers to have used `33%` width on 3 sibling floats. It's pretty common.

Comment: Yep, That I can understand, but why would they need to set the width of 99.99% for the same issue, wouldn't that cause sibling floats to drop in any browser (unless the other float had a width of 0.01%)? I would think the 99.9% is more `hasLayout` related than IE6 subpixel rounding related.

Comment: 99.9% isn't some magical keyword to trigger hasLayout, any value other than `auto` would have been fine though. It could also be that they specified 1px padding on a 99% width element since 100% width + 1px padding would bust.

Comment: It could also be related to horizontal scrollbars like http://www.longren.org/2006/09/27/wrapping-text-inside-pre-tags/ . It would really help seeing the page where he saw the issue. There can be dozens of explanations.

Comment: It's also highly possible that the element already had a property/value triggering hasLayout so the width didn't do anything special since it was already triggered.

Comment: Yeah definitely, but then again, setting width to 99.9% for `hasLayout` does appear to be a common misconception: http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/#comment-307 But as you said, there are many possibilities.